# Velocity with respect to distance (Output from Regression)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

This is probably a rookie question, but since I'm not an engineer, I beg your pardon and your help.

**Problem:**

I have the output of a regression: basically starting point, end point, start time, end time and some other coefficients, which gives me roughly the following equation for the velocity of a car

$v(s)=15*\log(s) + 31$

and now I'm struggling with the question for $s(t)$, i.e. which distance can I make in what amount of time?

I'm guessing that I have to restructure the equation so that

$v = \frac{s}{t}$ becomes $s=v*c$ and then differentiate but here I'm not sure I'm doing anything useful at all.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a *rookie question* at all, be sure.

$s$ being the distance and $v$ the velocity, you problem is to solve $$\frac{ds}{dt}=a\log(s)+b$$ which cannot be solved (except numerically, I presume). However, you can write it as $$\frac{dt}{ds}=\frac 1{a\log(s)+b}$$ and integrating $$t=\int\frac {ds}{a\log(s)+b}$$ which is not simple and cannot be solved in terms of elementary functions.

Changing variable $$a\log(s)+b=a x\implies s=e^{-\frac{b}{a}}\,e^{x}\implies ds=e^{-\frac{b}{a}}e^{x}\,dx$$ makes $$t=\frac{e^{-\frac{b}{a}}}a\int \frac{e^{ x}}{x}\,dx=\frac{e^{-\frac{b}{a}}}a\,\text{Ei}(x) $$ where appears the [exponential integral function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral).

Back to $s$, this then gives $$t=\frac{e^{-\frac{b}{a}} }{a}\,\text{Ei}\left(\frac{b}{a}+\log (s)\right)$$ which you cannot inverse to get $s$ as a function of $t$.

Now, using your numbers $a=15,b=31$, we can generate tables
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
t & s \\
 2 & 179.893 \\
 4 & 411.555 \\
 6 & 661.773 \\
 8 & 923.871 \\
 10 & 1194.73 \\
 12 & 1472.54 \\
 14 & 1756.09 \\
 16 & 2044.55 \\
 18 & 2337.28 \\
 20 & 2633.81
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: Thanks a lot! 

Prior to your answer I used Excel's Goal Seek since I only need just a small number of values - but your solution is far more elegant!